# How many times has an NHL hat trick been scored with only 3 shots?

Tags: trivia, statistics, ice-hockey, nhl

How many NHL players have (like Colorado's [Nathan MacKinnon on 20th February 2015](http://www.nhl.com/gamecenter/en/recap?id=2014020889&navid=sb:recap&intcmpid=sb-highlights)) have had only three shots in a game and scored a hat trick?

Comment: This would be interesting to know, but I'm not sure a stat like this is even recorded.

Comment: Of course it's recorded.  Every game's box score records it :) If I have time I'll download the information needed to figure this out, but anyone can do so from freely available stats (given some time).

Answer (score 5):

Hockey Reference was able to at least partially answer this; I only searched on goals=3 and goals=4 (so a 5+ goal game wouldn't show up).

However, it seems to be a very common occurrence.  For example, it happened 7 times so far this season; Shawn Matthias (of Vancouver) scored 3 goals on 3 shots on 2/13 versus Boston.

According to my [Hockey-Reference search](http://www.hockey-reference.com/play-index/pgl_finder.cgi?request=1&player=&match=game&year_min=&year_max=&age_min=0&age_max=99&team_id=&opp_id=&is_playoffs=N&game_location=&game_result=&pos=S&c1stat=shots&c1comp=eq&c1val=3&c2stat=goals&c2comp=eq&c2val=3&c3stat=&c3comp=gt&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=gt&c4val=&order_by=goals&order_by_asc=&offset=200), it occurred 233 times since 1987 (when their database begins keeping track).  It also showed 10 4 goal-4 shot games.  I didn't look beyond that.

Comment: I'm glad to see that no one matched 3 goals on 2 shots... though wonder if that's impossible or not (not familiar with the intricacies of scoring in the NHL)

Comment: It actually is possible! If a team scores an own-goal, the goal gets credited to the last player on the other team who played the puck; however, that player is not credited with a shot on goal. Here's a list of players who scored a goal in a game where they had 0 shots: http://hkref.com/tiny/awYmJ